# Installing IIS from c# code on 64bit machine with 32bit application

Tags: c#, iis, 32bit-64bit

I'm trying to install IIS on a 64bit machine.
The installation is a 32bit c# application.

The code is as follows (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892334/using-pkgmgr-to-install-iis-7)):

```
Process proc = new Process();
string cmd = @"C:\Windows\System32\pkgmgr.exe";
string cmdargument =
            @" start /w pkgmgr /iu:IIS-WebServerRole;IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;
            IIS-StaticContent;IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;IIS-HttpRedirect;IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;
            IIS-ASPNET;IIS-NetFxExtensibility;IIS-ASP;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;IIS-ISAPIFilter;IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;
            IIS-LoggingLibraries;IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-HttpTracing;IIS-CustomLogging;IIS-Security;IIS-WindowsAuthentication;
            IIS-RequestFiltering;IIS-IPSecurity;IIS-Performance;IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;
            IIS-ManagementConsole;IIS-ManagementScriptingTools;IIS-ManagementService;WAS-WindowsActivationService;
            WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI;NetFx3";

proc = Process.Start(cmd, cmdargument);
proc.WaitForExit();
proc.Close();
```

When the application is compiled to "AnyCPU" everything works fine.
But it is compiled with "x86" the PkgMgr window shows an error: "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format".

I also tried to run the PkgMgr from the wow32 folder but it didn't work as well.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Very hard to come up with a reason to not use AnyCPU.

Comment: The installer application is running some code that must be compiled with x86. Otherwise, it would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, it is not optimal but it works.
I'm wrapping the PkgMgr execution with an AnyCPU compilation and does the work.

I still would like to find a more "right" solution.